# c++ alternative member definition

Tags: c++, class, syntax, c++14, member

In C++ you can define members the following way:

```
struct test {
    using memberType = int(int);
    /*virtual*/ memberType member;
};

int test::member(int x) { return x; }
```

With C++14 is there any way to define the member inside the class definition, for instance with a lambda ?

Comment: What's the benefit of the type alias? You've already found that it detracts from your ability to define the member inside the class.

Comment: @chris maybe he wants to use it as type for `std::function` ?

Comment: I'm just exploring the dark corners of the c++ standard to find new ways to write more generic code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think that's possible, but you could do it if the member is a pointer to function

```
struct test {
    int (*member)(int) = [](int x){return x;};
};
```

since a lambda with an empty capture list is actually a regular function

Comment: And you can also keep your alias if you change it to `using memberType = int (*) (int);`

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could think of us to use a `std::function<>` object, but you have to pass the instance (can't think of how it could be automatically bound..)

```
struct foo {
    using T = int(foo&, int);

    int b;
    std::function<T> x = [](foo& f, int a) { return a * f.b; };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

you're looking to write something like this:

```
struct test {
  auto member_impl = [this]() {
  };
};
```

This fails on (at least) three counts:

1. You can't declare a non-static member `auto`.
2. You can't name the type of a lambda (so it must be auto)
3. `this` is not available at the time of defining the class.

Short answer, no.

but you can write:

```
struct test {
  auto member_impl() {
  };
};
```

which is about as short as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

I guess [5.1.5/3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#3) is what prevents you to use a lambda the way you would use it, I'm sorry:

> [...] A lambda-expression shall not appear in an unevaluated operand (Clause [expr]), in a template-argument, in an alias-declaration, in a typedef declaration, or in the declaration of a function or function template outside its function body and default arguments. [ Note: The intention is to prevent lambdas from appearing in a signature.  — end note ] [...]

That said, C++14 does let you define a member type using templates, as in the following example:

```
template<typename F>
struct S;

template<typename R, typename... Args>
struct S<R(Args...)> {
    using member = R(Args...);
    R operator()(Args...) { return R{}; }
    member M;
};

template<typename R, typename... Args>
R S<R(Args...)>::M(Args...) { return R{}; }

int main() { S<void(int)> s; }
```